# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on self.view using Xcode 6 only

Tags: ios8, xcode6, exc-bad-access

Getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on this `NSLog(@"%@",self.view);` line.

And this issue I am facing only in Xcode6. It is seamlessly working in older version of xcode.

Anyone please helps me on it.

Please find attached image.

[image]